# How to change the color of programmatically added buttons?

Tags: android, user-interface, button

I recently started making a chess-like game for android. The first thing I needed was to make the 8 by 8 board. I figured adding 64 buttons and organizing them in the XML wouldn't be much efficient, so I found a way to create them programmatically using a simple 8x8 matrix of buttons. Until this point, everything worked as intended, and I had this:
[image]

The next thing I tried was to change the colors of the buttons to match a chessboard. On the internet I found some ways of doing it, but pretty much all of them just made my buttons invisible, and did not change their color.
[image]

Here's the onCreate method (the only thing I modified so far):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

    //GETTING SCREEN DIMENSIONS
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int width = size.x;
    int height = size.y;

    //SETTING THE BOARD
    int TILESIZE = width/8;
    LinearLayout back = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.back);
    LinearLayout[] rows = new LinearLayout[8];
    Button[][] tiles = new Button[8][8];

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        rows[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        back.addView(rows[i]);
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            tiles[i][j] = new Button(this);
            tiles[i][j].setWidth(TILESIZE);
            tiles[i][j].setHeight(tiles[i][j].getWidth());
            if((i + j) % 2 == 0){

                tiles[i][j].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                tiles[i][j].invalidate();
            }
            else{
                //TODO: Make tiles black
            }
            rows[i].addView(tiles[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

The XML file contains a single vertical linear layout called back.

My question is how can I make the buttons change color, and where am I doing something wrong. I would also gladly accept alternative (or better) ways to make the board.

Comment: I don't understand, you already make every second button white with `setBackgroundColor`, why wouldn't that work for the other buttons? With a different colour of course. If your layout background is black and you want the button background to be black they will appear "invisible" naturally. Just pick different colours.

Comment: the thing is, the setBackgroundColor isn't working. My code is supposed to make every second button white color, but it actually makes them invisible.

Comment: did you check the same code by removing tiles[i][j].invalidate(); line ?

Comment: Yes, I tried removing the invalidate line, and I tried removing the alpha chanel (the first two hex digits of the color) and any combination of them two, but the buttons are still invisible. I suspect it has something to do with me adding them programmatically and not in the XML.

Answer (score 0):

Change your loop like this and try

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        rows[i] = new LinearLayout(this);
        for(int j = 0; j < 8; j++){
            tiles[i][j] = new Button(this);
            tiles[i][j].setWidth(TILESIZE);
            tiles[i][j].setHeight(tiles[i][j].getWidth());
            if((i + j) % 2 == 0){

                tiles[i][j].setBackgroundColor(0xFFFFFFFF);
                tiles[i][j].invalidate();
            }
            else{
                //TODO: Make tiles black
            }
            rows[i].addView(tiles[i][j]);
        }

      back.addView(rows[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your `if` loop like this:

```
if((i + j) % 2 == 0)
    tiles[i][j].setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_blue_dark);

else
    tiles[i][j].setBackgroundColor(android.R.color.holo_red_dark);
```

You can define `black` and `white` colors in your `color.xml` file and add them instead using `tiles[i][j].setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));` and similarly for black.
But make sure, you use a different background so they are clearly visible.